# WHERE clause with strpos

Tags: sql, select

```
create table test(variable varchar(20), col001 real, col002 real);
insert into test values('col001',1,2);
insert into test values('col002'3,4);
```

Now, I'd like to query this to get a *submatrix*:

```
 select variable, col001, col002
 from test
 where strpos("col001,col002", variable) > 0
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: "col001,col002" is a delimited identifier, i.e. the dbms thinks it's a column name. Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: @jarlh: please add as a reply, so that I can accept.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"col001,col002"` is a delimited identifier, i.e. the dbms thinks it's a column name. Use single quotes for string literals.

I.e.

```
select variable, col001, col002
from test
where strpos('col001,col002', variable) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `STRPOS` is MsSQL:
reference : [SQL Server: any equivalent of strpos()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099940/sql-server-any-equivalent-of-strpos)
you can write the query like this in MsSQL:

```
SELECT variable, col001, col002
FROM test
WHERE CHARINDEX('col001,col002', variable) > 0
```

Comment: And what tells you that the OP is using SQL Server?